# How to check whether an element is Present inside another element or not in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html code which add elements  dynamically.
On button click i wanted to check whether the elements present inside the 
div or not

**HTML** :

```
<div id="mainDiv">
<span class="child">span1</span>
</div>
<button id="check"></button>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$(function() {
$("#check").click(function(){
   // exist or not
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#check").click(function(){
   if ( $(".child").parents("#mainDiv").length == 1 )       
   { 
         //  the child element is inside the parent
   } 
    else
   {
           //it is not inside
   }
    });
});
```

hope it is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for child element inside parent. It means you know the parent element already exists. So, you should use jQuery context selector as

```
$(function() {
    $("#check").click(function(){
        // exist or not
        if($('.child', '#mainDiv').length) {
            console.log('Yes!! element exists');
        } else {
            console.log('Nope!!');
        }
    });
});
```

You can also use `$('#mainDiv').find('.child').length` to check if it contains the element with class `child`.

You can find more details on context selectors at http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-selectors